# Building persistent headers in list on scrolling level by level

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, scroll

I'm creating a list with dynamic amount of li-Items and classes from level-1 to level-X with PHP. According to the levels the list items are indented. As this list is getting longer and longer the visitor might lose context, when the less indented (indentation as hierarchy) items leave the viewport.

To prevent this irritation I started fixing the less-indented element to stay in the viewport till its sibling is going to take its place by scrolling.

But this does only work on the first level of indentation, but I'm trying to treat the following indented items the same way to group them and always present their context (hierarchy) within the viewport.

Just a simple list like this. Levels indicating indentation:

```
<ul>
    <li class="level level-1">1</li>
    <li class="level level-2">1.1</li>
    <li class="level level-2">1.2</li>
    <li class="level level-2">1.3</li>
    <li class="level level-1">2</li>
    <li class="level level-2">2.1</li>
    <li class="level level-2">2.1.1</li>
</ul>
```

I posted the one level example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/addorange/PWdEx/1/).

Maybe there is anyone who might have an idea?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to add a `level-x` in your PHP you can also add a data-attribute which gives us depth.  It just makes it easier to do some comparisons without having to do string manipulations later on.

In this example I did a quick search and replace on the level-x to add the data-attribute into the markup quickly but you can add both from PHP>  That means you can ignore the `housework` section of the demo code.

Then you would do the following with:

Javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

      // Just some housework to add in the correct CSS again
      $('li').each(function (index, el) {
          $(el).addClass('level-' + $(el).data('depth'));
      });
      //// end of housework

      allEls = $('.testList li');
      elOffsets = [];
      // Get and cache all the offsets of all li elements
      $.map(allEls, function (el, i) {
          elOffsets[i] = $(el).offset().top;
      });

      var clone = null;

      $(window).scroll(function () {
          //remove clone if there is one present
          if (clone) {
              clone.remove();
              clone = null;
          }
          var offScreenElIndex = null; // Initialize an index for the first element to be offScreen
          var scrollDistance = $(document).scrollTop() + 20; // add the fixed height of the clone 20px from css.
          $.each(elOffsets, function (i, elOffset) {
              // See if the elements position is offscreen (negative) according to latest scrollDistance
              if (elOffset - scrollDistance < 0) {
                  offScreenElIndex = i; // Set that as the offScreenElIndex
              } else if (elOffset - scrollDistance >= 0 && offScreenElIndex !== null && clone === null) {
                  // Else we are now at the next element in the list which is "onScreen" after the "offScreen" el and there hasn't been a clone made yet
                  //create a clone
                  el = $('.testList li').get(offScreenElIndex); // get the list element to clone (the previous one to this "i" as it is "offScreen")
                  if ($(el).data('depth') > 1) {
                      // if the depth of this is bigger than one, make the "cloned" element the previous depth
                      el = $(el).prevAll('[data-depth="' + ($(el).data('depth') - 1) + '"]').get(0);
                  }
                  createClone(el);
              } else {
                  // if no exit to stop the foreach and wait for the next scroll event.
                  return false;
              }
          });
      });

      function createClone(el) {
          clone = $('<div/>')
              .addClass($(el).attr('class'))
              .addClass('clone fixed')
              .text($(el).text());
          $('.testList').prepend(clone);
      }
  });
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/3BDA3/1/